# how to pass a substring without actually creating an temporary object in c++

Tags: c++, string

Lets say I have a function

```
str_rev(string &s, int len) {}
```

which reverses the string s of length len

I want to reverse a substring of long string starting at index 5 and of length 10

for this I was forced to first call substring function and then call the str_rev function passing the substring

```
sub_string = long_str.substr(5, 10)
str_rev(sub_string, 10);
```

Is there any way to achieve this without actually creating a temporary object?

Comment: Aside from not using iterators/`std::reverse`, why would your original function need to take the size?

Answer (score 8):

Make your function take iterators (or, rather, use `std::reverse()`) and pass in iterators delimiting the substring.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you just want to do this:

```
std::string::iterator it = long_str.begin() + 5;
std::reverse(it, it+10);
```

Comment: Hmm... I wonder why there's no reverse_n.  Does anybody know if there's a good reason for that?

Comment: @Eugen:  I don't understand, how does the one obviate the other?

Comment: @PigBen: Because there doesn't need to be. Just add `n` to your starting iterator.

Comment: @GMan:  But that would only work on random access iterators.  Regardless, I just thought of the probable reason.  It's because reverse requires a valid last iterator from the start, because it's iterating from both sides.  Whereas functions like copy, generate and fill can use insert iterators to create elements along the way.

Comment: @PigBen: You can use `std::advance`. But yes, you're right; I was hoping you'd ask "why is there `fill_n`, for example?" But you figured it out. :)

Comment: @PigBen: err, I was thinking about something else... Deleted the useless comment...

Answer (score 2):

rather than `int len`, pass a parameter which defines a range:

```
str_rev(string &s, const t_unsigned_range& range) {/* ... */}
```

and

```
str_rev(long_str, t_unsigned_range(5,10));
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use char* instead of std::string, you can pass a pointer to any two chars in the string. However, using char* is generally not a good idea.

Comment: What you mean is iterators, then, like sbi suggests.

Comment: No, I meant pointer. I didn't know you can have an iterator for the individual chars of a std::string. Thanks for the new insight.

Comment: It makes no sense to say "I didn't mean iterator, I meant pointer". A pointer _is_ a random-access iterator.

Comment: I know that. What I meant was that I didn't know you could use a random access iterator over the chars of a std::string. I thought that in order to use pointers to individual chars, you had to use a char*, and therefore pointers (even though they can be used in place of iterators, in this case they are still technically pointers)